# Differential equation of a conic with given constraints

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, conic-sections

The differential equation of all conics whose axes coincide with the axes of coordinates is of order

(A) 2

(B) 3

(C) 4

(D) 1

I know that the general equation of a conic is:

[image]

If I apply Lagrange multiplier theorem I get:
[image]

How should I continue with this problem?

Comment: A little progress: If I am not wrong, the equations that you got are those lines which are parallel to the axes. In that case, either of $a, b,$ or $h$ must be zero. But $a, b$ can't be zero (the curve won't be quadratic then). So $h = 0$.

Comment: So once we've eliminated $h$, you'll see that effectively there are $4$ (not $5$ as it may seem) constants. So it'd be a fourth degree differential equation. Otherwise you can check by differentiation per se. I am getting $4$ as the answer - unless of course I am missing something.

Comment: what is the given answer? Could you please verify what I've done?

Comment: The given answer is 2.

Comment: Ok. I got the answer. The reason why I missed the first time was that I was using the condition that the axes are parallel to the coordinate axes. The missing part was that the axes *coincided* with the coordinate axes. So, applying this one more constraint gives $g = f = 0$. That means, the equation of all such conics is $ ax^2 + by^2 + c = 0 $ or $ x^2 + \frac ba y^2 + \frac c a = 0 $. Two arbitrary constants $\implies$ second degree.

Comment: The question asks about **differential** equations. I don't see any discussion of differential equations below. Equations, yes; differential equations, no.

Comment: The equation of a conic is **always** second degree, it doesn't matter how it's translated or even rotated. Having axes coincident with the coordinate axes is irrelevant.

Comment: @bubba, well, it may seem so, but it isn't so. My answer first applies all the given constraints on general equation of conic. Once I've got the general equation of conics satisfying these constraints (conic axes are the coordinate axes), i.e., the equation $ x^2+\dfrac ba y^2+ \dfrac ca=0 $, I say that there are *two* arbitrary constants. So, (to eliminate them), you have to differentiate the equation two times. The order will be $2$. Still, I'll edit my answer in case you want explicit discussion on differential equations.

Comment: @bubba, is that fine now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equations that you got are those lines which are parallel to the axes. In that case, either of $a,b$ or $h$ must be zero. But $a,b$ can't be zero (the curve won't be quadratic then). So $h=0$. Also the axes coincide with the coordinate axes. So, applying this one more constraint gives $g=f=0$. That means, the equation of all such conics is $ax^2+by^2+c=0$ or $x^2+\dfrac ba y^2+ \dfrac ca=0$. Two arbitrary constants, so second order.

**EDIT**:

$$x^2+\dfrac ba y^2+ \dfrac ca=0$$

Differentiating w.r.t $x$ gives:

$$2x+2\dfrac ba y\cdot y'=0$$

or:
$$\dfrac x {y\; y'}+\dfrac ba =0$$

Another differentiation gets us rid of all the arbitrary constants, and we end up with a $2$nd order differential equation.

Comment: I think you're trying to say second *order* and not second *degree*.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @VijayRaghavan, edited.