# Differential equation of all second-order central curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to solve the task: Write the differential equation of all second-order central curves whose principal axes coincide with the x and y axes. The answer is $x(y''y+y'^2)-y'y=0$.
I tried to differentiate hyperbola and ellipse formulae $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}\pm\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ $$Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2+2Dx+2Ey+F=0$$ but it doesn't work.
I tried to integrate the answer $$\frac{y''}{y'}+\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{x}$$ It's a inhomogeneous equation. Integrate homogeneous part first $$\frac{y''}{y'}=-\frac{y'}{y}$$ $$ln(y')=-ln(y)+ln(C)$$ $$y'=\frac{C}{x}$$ $$\frac{y^2}{2}=C_1x+C_2$$ $$C_1'x+C_2'=0$$ $$C_1'=\frac{1}{x}$$ $$C_2'=-1$$ $$C_1=ln(x)+ln(\bar{C_1})$$ $$C_2=-x+\bar{C_2}$$ $$\frac{y^2}{2}=x(ln(x)+ln(C_1))-x+C_2$$ but I can't differentiate this into the answer either. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can integrate the known answer directly.

\begin{align}
\int (x(yy''+(y')^2)-yy')\mathrm dx=\int 0\mathrm dx\\
\int x(yy''+(y')^2\mathrm dx=\frac{y^2}{2}+c,
\end{align}
using integration by parts, $u=x$, $dv=(yy''+(y')^2)\mathrm dx=\mathrm d_x(yy')\mathrm dx$,
\begin{align}
xyy'=y^2+c.
\end{align}
This equation is separable.

Comment: What is meant by *central curve*?

Comment: @Allawonder A second-order curve that has a unique centre of symmetry (the centre of the second-order curve) is called a central curve. [link](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Second-order_curve)

Comment: Refer to [*mathoverflow*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217719/differential-equation-of-conics) and other [*post*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493147/differential-equation-of-a-conic-with-given-constraints).

Comment: How can you call the middle expression "inhomogeneous"? The equation is not even linear. But its terms are all easily integrable, are all logarithmic derivatives, so you should just go to $\ln|y'|+\ln|y|=\ln|x|+c$.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann, as I understand, in a homogeneous expression a common multiplier can be put out of brackets, here it is impossible.

Comment: There is homogeneous and there is homogeneous. Both do not apply here. The one is for linear DE that have right size zero or equivalently the zero function as solution. The other is for first order equations $y'=f(x,y)$ where the right side can be written as a function of $\frac{y}{x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ax^2+by^2=1$$
$$ax\;dx+by\;dy=0\quad\implies\quad y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{ax}{by}\tag 1$$
$$d(y')=-\frac{a}{by}dx+\frac{ax}{by^2}dy $$
$$y''=\frac{d(y')}{dx}=-\frac{a}{by}+\frac{ax}{by^2}y'\tag 2$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ :
$$\frac{a}{b}=-\frac{yy'}{x}=\frac{y''}{-\frac{1}{y}+\frac{xy'}{y^2}}$$
$$-yy'(-\frac{1}{y}+\frac{xy'}{y^2})=xy''$$
$$yy'-xy'^2=xyy''$$
$$\boxed{x(yy''+y'^2)=yy'}$$

Comment: How did you invent the very first equation, $ax^2+by^2=1$?

Comment: From $y'=-\frac{ax}{by}$ you can directly go to $\frac{yy'}{x}=-\frac{a}{b}$ so that in the derivative of that expression the constants are eliminated. This shortens the computation considerably.

Comment: @Stepan Pavlov: There is no invention at all. $\frac{x^2}{A^2}\pm\frac{y^2}{B^2}=ax^2+by^2$ with $a=\frac{1}{A^2}$ and $b=\pm\frac{1}{B^2}$.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann. Right. Well done !